# Redirect all URLs to a single URL

Tags: nginx, redirect, virtualhost

I have a machine `foo00` whos `CNAME` is `foo`. With `nginx` I can access my site from the following URLs:

```
foo/
foo00/
foo.domain.local/
foo00.domain.local/
```

How can I configure `nginx` so that all are redirected `foo.domain.local`?

I tried the following:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name foo.domain.local;
    return 301 $scheme://$host$request_uri;

}
```

This redirects `foo/` to `foo.domain.local/` but not `foo00/` or `foo00.domain.local`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Add another server block for the other domains you want to redirect:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foo00.domain.local;

    return 301 http://foo.domain.local;
}
```

Or if you want to preserve the URI, you can use this:

```
return 301 http://foo.domain.local$request_uri;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add all your domains like

```
server_name sub.domain.tld domain.tld othersub.domain.tld andsoon.tld;
```

(don't forget the ";" at the end of directives).

Take a look the the [rewrite documentation of nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) for further options regarding adding possible URL parameters if you need that.

Comment: I changed `server_name` to `foo.domain.local foo00.domain.local` but it doesn't make a difference. This is a single a machine, single domain, I just want everything redirect using the CNAME.